# JQuery busy indicator doesn't disable keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have integrated a Jquery busy indicator in my app from this link: http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1331/

It doesn't let the user click on input elements while loading. But if I press tab I can easily navigate to those input elements and enter whatever I want and press enter on button to send a service call. This defeats the whole purpose of busy indicator. Any idea how I can fix it?

This is the css:

```
.busy-modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .busy-center
    {
        z-index: 1000;
        margin: 300px auto;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        background-color: White;
        border-radius: 10px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
    }
    .busy-center img
    {
        height: 128px;
        width: 106px;
    }
```

Comment: you could use JS/jQuery to toggle the `disabled` attribute on your inputs

Comment: i can't.. im already using that property on elements based on other requirements.

Comment: can you provide your relevent HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually disabling keyboard input on busy indicator. Here's how I did it:

In my angularJS controller I declared a variable that will decide whether to disable keyboard input or not

```
$scope.disableKeys = false;
```

then I added following code that disables keyboard input

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    if ($scope.disableKeys == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

this is my busyIndicator function:

```
function busyIndicator(type)
{
    if(type == 1)
    {           
        $scope.disableKeys = true;
        $(".busy-modal").show();
    }
    else if (type == 0)
    {
        $scope.disableKeys = false;
        $(".busy-modal").hide();
    }
}
```

Finally, calling this function:

```
//to show busy indicator
busyIndicator(1);

//to hide busy indicator
busyIndicator(0);
```

and that's it.